# SQL Server and implicit conversion of types

Tags: sql, sql-server

Where does SQL Server do implicit conversion and what are the rules it follows? I.E when does it convert the left side of the equality operator over the right side?

```
Foobar
id int not null 
quantity int not null
quantityTest byte not null
date varchar(20) not null
dateTest datetime
```

```
SELECT id
FROM Foobar
WHERE quantity > '3'

SELECT id
FROM foobar
WHERE quantityTest > 3

Select id
FROM foobar
WHERE date = 20120101
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [SQL Server Data Type Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the list you are after [DataType Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

In your examples:

```
WHERE quantity > '3'
```

'3' is cast to int, matching quantity

```
WHERE quantityTest > 3
```

No casting required

```
WHERE date = 20120101
```

20120101 *as a number* is being cast to a date, which is too large. e.g.

```
select cast(20120101 as datetime)
```

This is different from

```
WHERE date = '20120101'
```

Where the date *as a string* can be cast.

If you go down a third of the [CAST and CONVERT reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to the section Implicit Conversions, there is a table of implicit conversions that are allowed.  Just because it is allowed doesn't mean it will work, such as (20120101 -> datetime).

Answer (score 6):

There is a chart [here on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) (also shown below) which shows all explicit and implicit data type conversions that are allowed for SQL Server system-supplied data types. Also it explains the conversions which are NOT allowed etc.

It explains

```
-Explicit Conversions
-Implicit Conversions
-Conversions not allowed
...
```

[image: Data type conversion table sql]