# Why doesn't an integer value >2147483647 give the "varchar value overflowed an int column" error?

Tags: sql-server

I have a varchar(18) column that stores these values: '28412661022','2147483647',and '312231'.

When I execute this query: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN=28412661022`, the query finishes successfully. But when I execute this query: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN=2147483647`, I get the expected "conversion of the varchar value '28412661022' overflowed an int column" error.

Do you know why that happens? 28412661022>2147483647, which I believe is the maximum allowed integer for SQL Server.

Comment: because of an implicit conversion to `bigint`. **correction -- numeric

Comment: Take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297547/sql-server-and-implicit-conversion-of-types

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't follow how the implicit conversion works in the one case but not the other.

Comment: varchar(18,0)? is it numeric(18,0) or varchar(18)?

Comment: I meant varchar(18), sorry.

Answer (score 0):

test table:

```
create table t (col varchar(18))
insert into t values ('2147483647'),('28412661022')
```

If your value is able to be implicitly converted to the default `int` you get an error from the value `'28412661022'`:

```
select * 
from t
where col>1
```

> The conversion of the varchar value '28412661022' overflowed an int column.

---

```
select * 
from t
where col>28412661021
```

returns: 28412661022

---

If you specify a number larger than the max `int`, it will use the smallest `numeric` or `decimal` data type that fits your value. If that precision/scale is not enough for all values in the table you can get the following error:

```
select * 
from t
where col>2147483648
```

> Error(s), warning(s): Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

Comment: I think I get it. In the first example (`where col>1`), the two datatypes are varchar (from the column definition) and int (from the where clause). Int has the higher precedence, so we try to convert everything to int. That doesn't work for 28412661022.

In the second example, 28412661021 is a bigint, not an int, so we convert the varchar values to bigint. This works.

In the third example, we're again trying to convert varchar values to int.

Comment: @Avyncentia Be sure to check out the link that Egbert posted in his comment: [SQL Server and implicit conversion of types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13297547/2333499)